# Deserializing inherited types without explicit XmlArrayItem attribute

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
<MyEntity>
    <Vehicles>
        <Car />
        <Truck />
    </Vehicles>
</MyEntity>
```

I want to deserialise it into the following structure:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Vehicle[] Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle {}
public class Car : Vehicle {}
public class Truck : Vehicle {}
```

Is it possible to do this without having to decorate the MyEntity.Vehicles property with an XmlArrayItem attribute for each possible vehicle type? I may get new types of Vehicles that I don't know about at compile time, but are discoverable at run time.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think, of short of adding the attributes, is to implement IXmlSerializer on MyEntity and handling it manually. Of course you would also need someway of registering handlers for the different vehicle types.